# C++: Problems creating a child class within a parent class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a project that involves a class A that contains a few child classes (childB, childC, childD). My overly simplified goal was to have something like this

```
#include <string>

class A{
public:
   childB cb;                       <<Error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed
   childC cc;                       <<Error C4430:    "                            "
   childD cd;                       <<Error C4430:    "                            "

   A(){
      cc.setString("xyz");          <<Error C2039: 'cc' is not a member of A
   }
};

class childB : public A{
public:
   int value;
};

class childC : public A{
private:
   std::string str;
public:       
   void setString(std::string s){
      str = s;
   }
   std::string getString(std::string s){
      return str;
   }
};

class childD : public childB{
public:
   double value;
};

#include "classA.h"

int main (){
   A a;
   a.cc.getString();               <<Error C2228: left of '.getString()' must have class/struct/union
}
```

From this point I would have multiple things in main that would set the values of the different child classes, but when compiling I am getting numerous errors telling me that cb, cc, cd are not members of A. Additional errors are also listed.

Is there any reason why I wouldn't be able to add a child class to the parent class as shown?

Comment: For one thing, since `childB` is a subclass of `A` and `A` has a member variable of type `childB`, `childB` will also have to have a member variable of type `childB`, which will have to have *another* member variable...  Why do you think `A` needs to contain instances of its own subclasses?

Comment: I was making a linked list of A* and wanted and easy way to be able to have all three types of child classes available so I could switch between them at any moment. This would be based on a check string I would pass to the class.

Comment: You have a fundamental problem with your design. You can't have a base class contain an instance of a derived class. That would create an infinitely-sized object. Try to draw a diagram of an instance of such an object and you'll see the problem.

You'll have to explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If these definitions worked they'd be defining classes of infinite size. You wouldn't have enough memory to store these.

Comment: Ok I see where I went wrong with the infinite creating of the classes. Would something along the lines of creating the linked list of `A*` and the calling new/delete of the child classes at the position every time that I need to change the class type potentially work?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "change the class type". An object cannot change type once it's been created. However, if you just mean that you want a heterogeneous list that has some objects of type `childB` and some objects of type `childC`, then you can just leave out the members in `A`, and just call the appropriate `new` operator to create what you want, when you want.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of creating a class that would create 1 object of each of the 3 child classes. Then I could pick if I was pulling info from `ChildB`, `ChildC`, or `ChildD`.

Comment: Then don't make `childB` etc. inherit from `A`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible for a parent class to have an instance of a child class. You can use a child class pointers instead of child class objects for your purpose.

Define child classes in separate header files.

Add forward declarations of child classes in parent class header file.

Use child class pointers instead of child class objects.

Initialize child class pointer members of parent class with corresponding child class objects in a parent method such as init(). Do not initialize them in parent constructor since it will make an infinite recursion. You will have to move the init() method to a cpp file and include child class header files in that.

Comment: Assuming that you mean to call new on the child classes in the base class ctor, this by itself doesn't help, since you'd have infinite recursion.